# Insufficient Privileges error on getannouncements() method

Tags: apex, community, chatter, collaborationgroup

We have a created a Chatter group in salesforce. A group manager can post Announcements on the group we need to display this announcement on the community portal.

I am using `ConnectApi.ChatterGroups.getannouncements()` method but it is throwing an error saying

> Insufficient Privileges: You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Reasons you can get that error message include but aren't limited to:

- Does the user has access to that group?
- Is the group public?
- Is the group in the Community?
- Are the users logged in on the community portal?